# Upload a custom file to Artifactory Pro with custom properties and buildinfo in script

Tags: maven, artifactory

We need to upload a custom file to Artifactory Pro in our build scripts (Linux & Windows) with the following requerements:

- target is a Maven repo
- groupId, artifactId and version are known
- pom should be generated (another maven projects will access to this artifact)
- custom properties should be defined (important!)
- generate build-info is nice to have

I've tried to use Artifact Maven plugin but it doesn't allow to upload custom file, only maven project build results

I suppose it may be done using RestAPI or cli tool, but I didn't find how.

Any ideas? (with working examples please)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using JFrog CLI?

- target is a Maven repo

No problem! with JFrog CLI you can upload to whatever repository you want

- groupId, artifactId and version are known

Great, use it as the path of deployment.

- pom should be generated (another maven projects will access to this artifact)

The CLI won't do that but you can use [this user plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/metadata/pommer) to do that.

- custom properties should be defined (important!)

Sure.

- generate build-info is nice to have

Hell yhee! :)

Here are the download link and the manual:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI
https://www.jfrog.com/getcli/